# How to set up switch between 2 game modules

Tags: python

I want to switch levels in my game by button pressing, but when I press at the button second time it doesn't switch level again. So how can I switch my levels by button pressing as much as I want to?
Code of first program:

```
def switch_button(switch_button, mouse_x, mouse_y):
   if switch_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y):
      import first_level
```

Code of second program:

```
def switch_button(switch_button, mouse_x, mouse_y):
   if switch_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y):
      import second_level
```

Comment: Where are those functions? inside `first_level` and `second_level` modules?

Comment: yes, there are a lot of code. And I think that problem is not inside modules, but inside those functions

Comment: `import` loads module only once. If you use `import` again then it sees that it already loaded this module so it will not load it again. But using `import` this way is not good idea. Inside module you should keep code in functions and import it only once (at the beginning) and later runs functions from this module like `if switch...: second_level.run()`